# Are Apex graphs always Toroidal?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

An Apex graph is a grpah that is either Planar, or can be made planar by removing a single vertex.
Are all Apex graphs Toroidal?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v25i1p16/pdf) (Figure 7, first example), the graph consisting of two copies of $K_5$ with one identified vertex is not toroidal, but it is clearly apex by removing the identified vertex since $K_4$ is planar. So the answer is no.